# Cannot find EPEL packages for 6.5 - is there a vault somewhere?

Tags: centos, nagios

I cannot find EPEL packages for 6.5 - is there a vault somewhere? Specifically, I need the following RPMs but am unable to find them. This is in support of a legacy system, and we cannot upgrade it or use newer packages. For some bizarre reason, newer packages of Nagios are 4.x in CentOS 6.x, and the configs aren't compatible. Anyone know where I can find the following packages?

`nagios-plugins-dhcp-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-users-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-dummy-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-nrpe-2.15-2.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-file_age-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-pgsql-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-ide_smart-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-sensors-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-perl-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-linux_raid-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-check_jmx-1.2.3-1.x86_64
nagios-plugins-check_logfiles-3.5.3.2-2.x86_64
nagios-plugins-load-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-snmp-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-dns-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-disk-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-ntp-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-ifstatus-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-mysql-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-ssh-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-mysql_health-2.1.8.2-2.x86_64
nagios-plugins-ldap-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-smtp-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-log-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-mailq-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-swap-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-icmp-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-http-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-check_ntpq_offset-1.0.3-0.noarch
nagios-common-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-ping-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-procs-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagios-plugins-tcp-1.4.16-10.el6.x86_64
nagiosgraph-1.4.4-1.el6.noarch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nagios-plugins-xxxx-1.4.16 **-10** are originally Fedora 21 packages. You can build all packages from the `nagios-plugins-1.4.16-10.el7.src.rpm` source package : `$ rpmbuild -bb nagios-plugins.spec`

Link: http://dl.marmotte.net/rpms/redhat/el7/x86_64/nagios-plugins-1.4.16-10.el7/nagios-plugins-1.4.16-10.el7.src.rpm

Setting up an unprivileged rpm-build environment in /home/[user]/ : https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13